# How Do I plot a function that also includes a straight vertical line (such as x=2?)

Tags: python, function, graph, piecewise

For my program I'm attempting to have the user input attributes of a cantilever beam and from their input the program would output a shear diagram. I'm starting off simple with a singular downward load (user inputs point on beam where this load occurs and the load value). I figured a piecewise function sort of setup would work, so here is my code below:

```
length = input("input the length of your beam: ")
load = input("input your load: ")
distl = input("input the distance from the wall where your load starts: ")
distr = input("input the disance from the wall where your load ends: ")

load = float(load)
load = -load

length = int(length)
distl = int(distl)
distr = int(distr)


i = 0
graph = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
while i<=length:

    if  distl < i < distr:
            graph[i] = load 
    else:
        graph[i] = 0

    i = i +1



plt.ylabel('Shear (V(x))')
plt.xlabel('x (meters)')
plt.plot(graph)
plt.show()
```

This ends up outputting the graph below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6m9f.png)

Can someone explain to me why this includes a slope and not simply a jump? Thanks.

Comment: You can't. But you can do a ton more data points so the line will look vertical to your eyes

Comment: @JBernardo well it is often difficult to achieve vertical appearance in the face of pixelization. `matplotlib.pyplot.step` does plot vertical line segments, `matplotlib.pyplot.plot` can be used to plot arbitrary lines segments.

Answer (score 2):

(Update:) Maybe you're looking for `matplotlib.pyplot.step(X, Y, ...)`:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> X = range(8)
>>> Y = [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2]
>>> plt.step(X, Y)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x000004124CEC0090>]
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib "step" plot]

---

It is possible to explicitely request vertical lines by giving, for each point, both Y and Y coordinates:

```
>>> X = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
>>> Y = [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2]
>>> plt.plot(X, Y)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x000004124CEC0090>]
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib plot with jumps]

To plot *only* horizontal lines or *only* vertical lines, use matplotlib's `hlines` or `vlines`, respectively.

Want to avoid drawing a line segment? NaN's aren't connected:

```
>>> X = [0, 1, 1, 2,      2,       2, 3, 3, 4]
>>> Y = [2, 2, 3, 3, float('NaN'), 4, 4, 2, 2]
>>> plt.plot(X, Y)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000016250A0C060>]
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib plot with jumps with and without vertical lines]

---

To answer why the line segments are, by default, not vertical:
Because piecewise linear graphs approximate real-life functions much better than piecewise constant graphs (visually).

Compare
[image: Cosine approximated by linear segments]
vs.
[image: Cosine approximated by step function]

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain to me why this includes a slope and not simply a jump?

Because (in your graph) at x=2 the shear value is 0, and at x=3 it is -4. The only way to connect it is with a "slope" line - the hypotenuse, where the changes in x and the shear value are the two other sides of the triangle.

For that line to be vertical, the shear had to be simultaneously with value 0 and -4 at x=2, which is impossible (in non-quantum physics :D).

As rightfully pointed out in the comments, for that line to *appear* as vertical, you have to increase the resolution - have a lot more x data points.